# How to select the latest 100 distinct entries from a table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have been struggling to solve the following task although it appears to be quite easy:

> Select the latest 100 distinct entries from a table in SQLite

#### In Detail

I am using SQLite within a Objective-C based iOS 11+ project. The app database stores a list of `ToDo` entries in a table:

```
ID  |  Date        |  Note
----+--------------+---------
1   |  2019-10-01  |  ANote
1   |  2019-10-10  |  Note1
2   |  2019-10-11  |  Note2 
3   |  2019-10-12  |  Note1
```

Now I would like to query the latest 100 distinct Notes from this table:

- Sort the table by date in descending order
- Search through the entries and add the note to the result if it is not already in the result
- Stop once 100 distinct notes have been found

Sound easy, doesn't it :-)

#### What I tried

```
SELECT Note FROM ToDo ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 100

  Note1
  Note2
  Note1
  ANote
```

This does not work of course, since it does not look for distinct values (Note1 is included twice...). However, it returns the **notes in the correct date order**.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Note) FROM ToDo ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 100

  Note2
  Note1
  ANote
```

Now the `Note1` is included only once as expected, however the **date order is NOT correct** anymore.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Note), Date FROM ToDo ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 100

  Note1
  Note2
  Note1
  ANote
```

Including `Date` in the `SELECT` statement results in the correct date order by now the result is not distinct again.

```
SELECT Note FROM ToDo GROUP BY Note ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 100

  SQLite on iOS:       SQLiteBrowser on Mac

  Note2                Note1
  Note1                Note2
  ANote                ANote
```

While this **DOES WORK** when testing it in SQLiteBrowser on my Mac, it **FAILS** when running it in my iOS app. On iOS this approach has the same problem as `DISTINCT(Note)` and delivers the wrong date order

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Note) FROM (SELECT Note FROM Bookings ORDER BY Date DESC) AS n LIMIT 100

  Note2
  Note1
  ANote

SELECT Note FROM (SELECT Note FROM Bookings ORDER BY Date DESC) AS n GROUP BY Note LIMIT 100

  ANote
  Note1
  Note2
```

Again the no correct data order...

---

**So, I am running out of ideas.** It seems to be something special about SQLite on iOS that `SELECT Note FROM ToDo GROUP BY Note ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 100` does not work.

**Of course I could fix this in code. But any idea how to fix this within SQL?**

Comment: Does this work? `SELECT DISTINCT(Note), MAX(Date) FROM ToDo ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 100` -- also, avoid using a column named "Date" as it is a reserved word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue comes from the fact you need to specify which `Date` you want to consider for each distinct `Note`, in case there are multiples. You can solve this by grouping by Note and taking the max (or min, whichever you want) date:

```
SELECT Note, MAX(Date) AS Date 
FROM ToDo 
GROUP BY Note 
ORDER BY MAX(Date) DESC LIMIT 100
```